# gtkmm - FileChooserDialog - set_show_hidden(true); -> folders are hidden! 

Tags: windows, gtkmm

I don´t have a clue why this code doesn´t work on Windows. Hidden folders are not shown!

```
  Gtk::FileChooserDialog dialog("Please choose the ZUP-file directory",
      Gtk::FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER); 
dialog.set_show_hidden(true);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If its a bug, you can file it in the gnome bugzilla bugtracker site. I wonder if it shows files starting with a dot on windows or not with set_show_hidden(true)... If it doesn't, its prolly a bug in gtk+

Comment: i agree.  gtkmm (especially gtkmm3) has an awful lot of bugs like this.  the devil is in the details.